# How to create Enhanced Metafile (EMF) image file?

Tags: images

What software can I use to create an Enhanced Metafile (EMF) file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could, of course, also open an existing image and save it out as an EMF using an image viewer like [Irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com).

Comment: EMF is a vector format while IrfanView is bitmap oriented. Is it really the right tool for the task?

Answer (score 8):

[Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) supports WMF along with many other file formats. Do you specifically need *Enhanced* WMF?

Comment: Inkscape also supports EMF.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your complexity you can create a sketch in Powerpoint, and save it a wmf or emf.

Answer (score 0):

I link to use free and open source program [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) for this. It can open images and PDFs and these can be exported to EMF. Then you can use them in Microsoft programs such as Word or Powerpoint. With this your images are vector images and you don't lose resolution.